# Unable to publish to Azure after 2014 update

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an APS.net MVC project I have been publishing to azure for a while. I recently change laptop and moved to SQL Server 2014. Now when I try to publish I get 3 errors. The fist one looks to be the root course:

```
Error 3 .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1 Could not find stored procedure 'sp_addextendedproperty'
```

The other 2 errors are:

```
Error   4   Script execution error.  The executed script:
EXECUTE sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_DiagramPane1', @value = N'[0E232FF0-B466-11cf-A24F-00AA00A3EFFF, 1.00]
Begin DesignProperties = 
   Begin PaneConfigurations = 
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 0
         NumPanes = 4
         Configuration = "(H (1[40] 4[20] 2[20] 3) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 1
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 4 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 2
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 2 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 3
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (4 [30] 2 [40] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 4
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [56] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 5
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (2 [66] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 6
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [50] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration =         0   0   AMScan
```

and

```
Error   5   Web deployment task failed. (Could not deploy package.
Warning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL Server 2014 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1 Could not find stored procedure 'sp_addextendedproperty'.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
EXECUTE sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_DiagramPane1', @value = N'[0E232FF0-B466-11cf-A24F-00AA00A3EFFF, 1.00]
Begin DesignProperties = 
   Begin PaneConfigurations = 
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 0
         NumPanes = 4
         Configuration = "(H (1[40] 4[20] 2[20] 3) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 1
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 4 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 2
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 2 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 3
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (4 [30] 2 [40] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 4
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [56] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 5
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (2 [66] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 6
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [50] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 


  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.)     0   0   AMScan
```

Doing some research I understand that there are certain expended stored procedure in 2014 that are not available in Azure SQL however it seems this is the case for a number of earlier versions including 2012 which I was using previously.

Any thoughts on how to remedy this.

Cheers,
Kevin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [multiple options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee730904.aspx) available to you, but I think below 2 best meet your demand:

- Integrated in Visual Studio you have the [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh272686(VS.103).aspx). When you switch the target for the deployment to Azure SQL DB you'll get the list of incompatibilities, which you can then fix in the project. 
  Details on how to move a DB to Azure with SSDT: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156163.aspx
- Use the [SQL Server Migration Wizard](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/). This tool will inspect your database, allow you to select the items you want to migrate and then generate a migration script for you. 
  More details on how to use it: 
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prasanna/archive/2015/04/13/migrating-sql-server-on-premise-db-to-sql-azure-using-sql-server-migration-wizard.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156166.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I took the second option and had the database migrated in less than 5 minutes. Cheers!